# Which principal ideal rings are homomorphic image of principal ideal domain?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

A theorem of Hungerford (https://msp.org/pjm/1968/25-3/pjm-v25-n3-p11-p.pdf) states: Every PIR is a homomorphic image of a finite direct product of PID's. In the end, the author states a corollary, that a PIR is a finite direct product of PIDs iff the PIR has no non-zero nilpotent. My question is: Can we characterize those PIRs which are homomorphic image of a PID ?

Comment: That's not what Theorem 1 of the cited paper says.

Comment: @lhf: I know, the author says " direct sum" ... but he is perhaps using an old/odd convention. He actually means finite direct product

Comment: No, Theorem 1 says "direct sum of homomorphic images of PID", not " direct product of PID'".  The important difference is not sum x product.

Comment: @lhf : I don't understand what you mean ... if you read the proof, you will understand he means "product" (as indeed, arbitrary direct sums of rings is not a ring with unity, and for finitely many rings , they are same ) , also whether I say "homomorphic image" before or later "product" doesn't make any difference as every ideal of $R \times S$ is of the form $I \times J$ and $R\times S / I \times J \cong R/I \times S/J$ . For further discussion on this criteria , read https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25663/elementary-proof-wanted-every-local-principal-ideal-ring-is-a-quotient-of-a-pid

Comment: But the direct product of domains is not a domain again, so doesn't the order matter?  Maybe not?

Comment: @Randall : What does "direct product of domains not being a domain" has to do with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think so.

If it is a proper quotient of a PID, then it is a $0$ dimensional Noetherian ring (actually quasi-Frobenius, even), which by virtue of its Artinianness is a [special principal ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_ring#Structure_theory_for_commutative_PIR.27s).

Conversely, a special principal ring (I am led to believe from the wiki) is a quotient of a discrete valuation ring, which is of course a PID.

Comment: A special PIR is indeed a quotient of a DVR as can be seen from the paper of Hungerford that I linked. Thanks a lot for your answer.